# Given a node object how can I detect if it's first term (or term in a chosen vocabulary) contains a taxonomy image?

Tags: 6, nodes, taxonomy-terms

Using php code and a node object, how can I detect whether or not the node's first term (or term in a chosen vocabulary) has a taxonomy image? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`taxonomy_image_display`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--taxonomy_image--taxonomy_image.module/function/taxonomy_image_display/6) returns an empty string iff the term has no image.

Given a node `$node`, the terms are stored in `$node->taxonomy` as an array indexed by term ID (see [`taxonomy_nodeapi($node, $op = 'load')`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_nodeapi/6)).